# ¿Como puedo mostrar un mejor menú de ayuda?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar el menu de ayuda de mi script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, justo despues de (-sd,-cd,-ca,-mkdir,-ma) hay un molesto [ [...]]

¿Como puedo eliminar esto, para que asi quede muhco mas limpio mi menu de ayuda?

Muchas gracias.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse

class Config_args():

    def __init__(self):

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Gestor CMD")

        parser.add_argument("-md","--make_dir",help = "crear un directorio",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-a","--archive",help = "crear un archivo",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-dd","--del_dir",help = "borrar un directorio",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-da","--del_archive",help = "borrar un archivo",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-e","--entry",help = "entrar en un directorio",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-sf","--search_file",help = "buscar un archivo",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-sd","--search_dir",help = "buscar un directorio",nargs = "*",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-cp","--change_path",help = "cambiar de ruta",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-cd","--copy_dir",help = "copiar un directorio",nargs = "*",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-ca","--copy_archive",help = "copiar un archivo",nargs = "*",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-mdir","--move_dir",help = "mover un directorio",nargs = "*",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-ma","--move_archive",help = "mover un archivo",nargs = "*",metavar = '')
        parser.add_argument("-mss","--message",help = "introducir texto dentro de un archivo",nargs = "*",metavar = '')

        self.args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes probar a quitar de tu código en cada uno de esos elementos (-sd,-cd,-ca,-mkdir,-ma):

```
  'nargs = "*"'
```

Si necesitas pasar múltiples argumentos a esos elementos debes mantener el 'nargs'. Para poder ver cómo aplicarlo de la manera que mejor se ajuste a las necesidades de tu proyecto te dejo este enlace de referencia dónde detallan su uso y posibilidades que espero te sea de ayuda.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Comment: ¿Pero no lo necesito para añadir mas de un argumento después de dicho parámetro?

Comment: Sí que lo necesitas, pero eso no se refleja en tu pregunta. Completo la respuesta arriba con una URL que creo que te será de ayuda para tu problema y así ver cómo aplicar todas las posibilidades del 'nargs' .